# Graphical glitch for notification bubbles

Tags: release-juno, graphics, notification-badge

since few days i have some strange graphical glitch for notification bubbles from all application. Someone have the same problem? Some advice to how to fix it? 
Tnx.

[image]

Comment: Your notification says 'task terminated' for `sudo apt update`. Can you update/upgrade your system normally?

Comment: Someone on Reddit helped me. It seems that for some reason i've installed "dunst" (maybe as part of i3-vm package). I've uninstalled "dunst" and the notifications style turned back to normality :)